# Migrating .htaccess rules to Nginx

Tags: nginx

Please help me in conversion the .htaccess rules to Nginx

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^show\.php/(.*)$ show2.php?img=$1 [L]
RewriteRule   ^out\.php/([a-z]{1})(.*)$ out2.php?$1=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule   ^view\.php/(.*)$ view2.php?img=$1 [L]
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading the documentation for nearly 1hr I found it by myself :)

rewrite ^/view.php/(.*)$ /view.php?img=$1 last;

Comment: This merely highlights the fact that the documentation should be read FIRST. Only if you do not find what you're looking for in the docs, or cannot understand what they say, should you be asking for help on this or any other site.